# How to paste multiple times at once in Excel between data

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Say I have data like this

```
  A   B   C
1 Jim 1 10    
2 Jim 2 20
3 Jim 3 30
4 Tom 1 20
5 
6 
7 Jos 1 15
8
9
```

What I want is copy the row 2 and 3 then paste to row 5 and 6, and then 8 and 9, and so on. The blank rows are always 2.

There is a formula in the cell 2C and 3C that calculate the value in column B multiplied by cell C1.

So, the result would be like this

```
  A   B   C
1 Jim 1 10    
2 Jim 2 20
3 Jim 3 30
4 Tom 1 20
5 Tom 2 40 
6 Tom 3 60
7 Jos 1 15
8 Jos 2 30
9 Jos 3 45
```

The problem is I have to paste hundreds times that would be time consuming.

I would appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Would you check `column A multiplied by cell B1`? This column contains names.

Comment: Could you give formulae used for calculating blank cells?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, I meant column B multiplied by cell C1. I edited now.

Comment: Hi Juri Ruut, If you meant the formula I used in cell 2C, here it is =B2*C1

Comment: I think he wants `C5 = C4 * B5`, which is the same as his result.

Comment: @t.thielemans I see, I thought that this was the misunderstanding and mentioned that moment in my comment to my answer an hour ago. Let's wait for TS to clarify the problem.

Comment: @grozhd, I removed all my messages seen as though both work and both solve the two possible cases ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep in mind:

- You'll need to make sure you have a value in column A1, otherwise
  just increase the value of `i` to the second row with data.
- `Var` is a dummy variable used to keep track when a new name occurs.
- `firstValue` will contain the rownumber of the first row per name.

**Code**

```
Sub test()

Var = 0
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
        If Var = 0 Then
            firstValue = i - 1
            Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i - 1).Value + 1
            Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & firstValue).Value + Range("C" & i - 1).Value
            Var = Var + 1
        Else
            Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i - 1).Value + 1
            Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & firstValue).Value + Range("C" & i - 1).Value
            Var = Var + 1
        End If
    Else
        Var = 0
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow... this works like a magic. I must set For i = 2 To 9 to meet my requirement above. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi @t.thielemans, since the last row is not always the same. In the question above, the last row is 9. But in my data the last row is sometime at row 107, or 127, or 254. So if I use the code above, I should first check where the last row and then change the 'For i'. Any idea?

Comment: @Wakanina, I edited my answer. LastRow will look for the last piece of data in Column A! ;)

Comment: You're really my life saver. Thank you. BTW, I must add '+ 2' into 'LastRow', so the code will be like this 'LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2'. Once again thanks so much.

Comment: @Wakanina, why do you need to add +2?

Comment: Because if I do not add + 2, the results only up to Row 7. This mean, Josh will not be copied to Row 8 and 9.

Comment: @Wakanina, oh wow didn't think about that! I will add it to my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MakeRows()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, DataRng As Range, CopyRng As Range, TargetRng As Range

    Set Sh = Sheets(1) 'select your sheet here
                       'you can also do it like this = Worksheets("name")

    Set DataRng = Sh.Range("B2")
    Set TargetRng = Sh.Range("A4")

    While IsEmpty(TargetRng) = False
       TargetRng.Copy TargetRng.Offset(1, 0)
       TargetRng.Copy TargetRng.Offset(2, 0)

       Set CopyRng = Sh.Range(DataRng, DataRng.Offset(1, 1))
       CopyRng.Copy TargetRng.Offset(1, 1)

       Set TargetRng = TargetRng.Offset(3, 0)
       Set DataRng = DataRng.Offset(3, 0)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Works with relative references in cells 2C and 3C.

Comment: I have tested it. If you filled your rows exactly as TS described (note that there is formulas in 2C and 3C), it should have filled all the numbers correctly. I forgot about the name, but I have just edited it.

Comment: My code does exactly what I think TS is asking for. Why should I consider if rows 2 and 3 are filled or not? There is a problem formulated right here and my code solves it. Why wouldn't it work for anything higher than 3? It copies first three rows with formulas, so if you change 2 in the second row for 5 it will work with 5. I think you misunderstood the question. I get exactly the same result as he does.

Comment: Do you have relative references in formulas in cells 2C and 3C? Have you selected your sheet? What happened when you ran it? I have tested it on exact same data you showed here. It works for any number of rows also.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry your code worked as well. But first I have to select all the data until the last row. Thanks so much @grozhd